# 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController

Tags: ios

I am having a problem with this.
In my root view controller I am having a textfield & one button. I am giving a condition like if i entered 0 in textfield then only it should move to next view.
upto here it is working correctly. But now here is problem. Here I am having one button & given navigation to third view controller for that button. here i am getting error as

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
```

image ref: http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/8533/myp5.png

and i am giving action for button in first view as below

```
- (IBAction)Submit:(id)sender {

if([tf.text isEqual:@"0"])
{

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"   bundle:nil];

    SecondViewController *vc2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewControllerID" ];

    [self presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:NULL];

}  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at your screenshot, you either need to

1. Push your `SecondViewController` onto the existing navigation controller's stack instead of presenting it modally OR
2. You need to embed your `SecondViewController` in another navigation controller and then create and present **that** navigation controller modally from your SamplesViewController

Either way, `SecondViewController` needs to be embedded in a navigation controller before you can use Push Segues from it

Comment: In first option, I need to navigate to second view if textfield text is equal to 0 only. So if i push seconviewcontroller with existing navigation controller it is not checking with that if condition and navigating automatically. In second option also the same situation happens where it is not checking with if condition and navigating automatically

Comment: Your explanation is a little unclear, but I think what you want is to go to a particular view conditionally when that button is pressed.  Just connect the push segues from your source view controller (**not the button**) to your destination view controller (s) in XCode.  Then in the action associated with your button you can query the contents of the textfield and call `- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender` with the segue you want to invoke.

Answer (score 12):

Go To:

Editor--> Embed In --> Navigation Controller, to add `Navigation Controller` to your initial view

Comment: I have already added. check screen shot http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/8533/myp5.png

Answer (score 1):

Either embed your view controller in a Navigation controller or if there is a Navigation controller in the story board mak it the initial view controller

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem. My problem was I was using `model` segue style (rather that `push`) for one before the current controller because of that I think it broke the Navigation chain before already.

Comment: I need a similar scenario. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: @BijoyThangaraj Consider the scenario `A > B > C` where A,B,C are `ViewControllers` with `NavigationController` already at the start of A. Now you moved from `A > B` with `Model` animation. This will break the chain and you can't move from `B > C` To have this we need to add another `NavigationController` say `D` before (& targeting) `B` and move  from `A` to `D` with `Model` animation (which indirectly will move to `B`). So flow is like `A > (D) -> B > C`. Now further navigation flow is taken care by second `NavigationController`

Answer (score 0):

Embed your view controller in a `UINavigationController` is a good option if there is no `UINavigationController` in the storyboard. Otherwise you can select the `UINavigationController` and select the root view controller in the inspector pane, then drag it to the `UIViewController` you want to use as root. the screenshot is as below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a custom UIStoryboardSegue between the UINavigationController and the destination view controller:

```
-(void) perform
{
    assert([self.sourceViewController isKindOfClass:[MyNavigationController class]]);
    MyNavigationController *launchController = (MyNavigationController *) self.sourceViewController;
    [launchController setViewControllers:@[self.destinationViewController] animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me.when you set root view controller to first view and use *self.presentViewController* ,controller move to next view but instance of navigation controller is only for first view,third view required navigation instance so use *self.navigationController* instead of presentViewController.

```
NSString * storyboardName=@"Main";
                UIStoryboard *storybord=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
                 SecondViewController *vc=[storybord instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewControllerID"];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more of the explanation.

Comment: Yes, I added more explanation @Blip .